# Update Widget in Android

Tags: android, widget, reload

How can i update my widget in Android? I mean when i press a button on my widget it should update my widget.

Please friends Guide me a little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-05/msg01439.html

i hope this will surely solve ur problem

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/update-widget-in-onreceive-method.html